# Systemverilog - multiple process triggering same event

Tags: system-verilog

Why am I getting the result shown below? I would expect that multiple trigger to the update_ev event should cause the display "Main Loop ,.." to be executed twice. But it is only executed once.

```
program multiple_trigger();
  initial begin
     event update_ev;
     bit orResult, prev_orResult, A, B;

     // Multiple trigg logic
     fork
        begin : threadDisplay
           forever begin
              prev_orResult = orResult;
              // Update status
              @(update_ev);
              // Compute A OR B
              orResult = A | B;
              $display("\n Main Loop , %0t  A=%0b, B=%0b orResult=%0b",$time(), A, B, orResult);

              if (prev_orResult != orResult) begin
                 $display("\n In the IF condition, %0t  A=%0b, B=%0b orResult=%0b",$time(), A, B, orResult);
              end
           end // forever
        end : threadDisplay

        // 10 A=0
        begin : threadA
           #10;
           A = 1'b0;
           ->update_ev;
        end : threadA

        // 10 B=1'b1
        begin : threadB
           #10;
           B = 1'b1;
           ->update_ev;
        end : threadB
     join_none
     #100;
  end      
endprogram

// Actual Result----------------------------------------
     Main Loop , 10  A=0, B=1 orResult=1
     In the IF condition , 10  A=0, B=1 orResult=1
//-----------------------------------------------------

// Expected Result----------------------------------------
    Main Loop , 10  A=0, B=0 orResult=0
    Main Loop , 10  A=0, B=1 orResult=1
    In the IF condition , 10  A=0, B=1 orResult=1
// -------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event trigger `->` can appear to be stack depending on the scheduling order. The LRM states the scheduler *may* evaluate events in the same region in an indeterminate order. Every simulator I have used don't appear to randomized the event order; they tend to give priority to compiling order.

Lets give label names to the threads in fork. Then walk through a likely scenario.

- ***disp_thread*** will be the process with `forever`
- ***thread_A*** will be the process with `A = 1'b0;`
- ***thread_B*** will be the process with `B = 1'b1;`

The simulator executes ***disp_thread*** first and stops when it reaches `@(update_ev);`. Then ***thread_A*** will kicks off and immediately sleep (will walk up in `#10`). ***thread_B*** stats up and also sleeps for `#10`. With no operations scheduled, the simulate will incorrect the timestep. ***thread_A*** and ***thread_B*** wake up, and ***thread_A*** executes first and triggers `->update_ev` and finishes. ***disp_thread*** is now unblocked, the simulator has a choice: continue ***disp_thread*** or ***thread_B***. Often, it will pick to continue the ***disp_thread*** and start its second loop (because the forever is in the same process thread) and pause again at `@(update_ev);`. ***thread_B*** now get a change to run and it triggers `->update_ev` and finishes. Once again ***disp_thread*** is unblocked so it can run again.

If you moved the event triggers above the event wait statement you *might* see the `$display` message issued only once. However this is a brittle solution and not recommenced.

Instead use a nonblocking event trigger (`->>`). This will move the event trigger NBA region of the scheduler. Allowing both triggering threads to run and schedule updates before unblocking the ***disp_thread***. With this change the schedule will be as follows:

The simulator executes ***disp_thread*** first and stops when it reaches `@(update_ev);`. Then ***thread_A*** will kicks off and immediately sleep (will walk up in `#10`). ***thread_B*** stats up and also sleeps for `#10`. With no operations scheduled, the simulate will incorrect the timestep. ***thread_A*** and ***thread_B*** wake up, and ***thread_A*** executes first and *schedules* `->>update_ev` for the *NBA* and finishes. At this point the scheduler is still in the Active region; ***disp_thread*** is still blocked. ***thread_B*** (the only thing that can run currently run) will run and schedule `->>update_ev` for the *NBA* region and finishes. With noting that can run in the current region, the scheduler continues to the next non-empty region; NBA. the event trigger to `update_ev` both happen. The scheduler re-enters the active region with ***disp_thread*** now unblocked.

Note: If you plan on use this, keep it simple and make yourself very knowledgeable with the scheduling semantics ([IEEE std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 4). Predictability will become brittle with added complexity (such as unblocked blocking events triggering new events). When predictability breaks, it may happen randomly form different simulators, version, machines, OS, system time, system load, etc.

Comment: HI Greg, Thanks for your reply. I am intending to use this in my verification environment. It is suppose to solve the purpose of multiple processes (thread_A, thread_B ....) trying to inform one hearing process (disp_thread) about some change in the shared variable. The hearing process should then decide, irrelevant of the order in which the threads executed, that the final result is the same or different than the previous. Do you think ->> should solve the purpose?

Comment: `->>` should work in that case. Another option is to put a little delay after `@(update_ev)`; assuming if a little delay is acceptable.

Comment: I would never recommend putting a little delay in a testbench. You can wind up with things becoming unmanageable once you start putting delays all over the place just to define ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Both actual and expected outcomes are possible because it is a race condition. There is nothing to prevent the second ->update_ev from triggering before the @(update_ev) responds.

I usually recommend people avoid SV events and in this case, a function call would serve the desired purpose.

Comment: Hi Dave, If I do want the outcome to always behave as the actual, can I use the ->> operator?

Comment: Yes. But consider other mechanisms like a semaphore or mailbox to communicate between threads. Have the listing thread use a fork join_any to wait on the other processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
program multiple_trigger();
  initial begin
     event update_ev1, update_ev2;
     bit orResult, prev_orResult, A, B;

     // Multiple trigg logic
     fork
        begin : threadDisplay
           forever begin
              prev_orResult = orResult;
              // Update status
             @(update_ev1, update_ev2);
              // Compute A OR B
              orResult = A | B;
              $display("\n Main Loop , %0t  A=%0b, B=%0b orResult=%0b",$time(), A, B, orResult);

              if (prev_orResult != orResult) begin
                 $display("\n In the IF condition, %0t  A=%0b, B=%0b orResult=%0b",$time(), A, B, orResult);
              end
           end // forever
        end : threadDisplay

        // 10 A=0
        begin : threadA
           #10;
           A = 1'b0;
           ->>update_ev1;
        end : threadA

        // 10 B=1'b1
        begin : threadB
           #10;
           wait(update_ev1.triggered);
           B = 1'b1;        
           ->>update_ev2;
        end : threadB
     join_none
     #100;
  end      
endprogram
```